# How to array pass to the http post in angular 8?

Tags: angular8

`basket=[];`

I wan to this  basket array pass the post method

```
this.data.SaveShipment(this.basket).then(data=>{ });
```

I pass that array but network showed `400` bad requests How can I pass that 
How can I convert that array to Object

Comment: Show your API Call?

Comment: **[HttpPost("saveShipLocation")]**
    **public DataTable SaveShipLocation(Location Osh)**
        {
        
           **return Osh.SaveShipment();**
        }    //Asp.Net Core

Comment: From Angular not .NET

Comment: **SaveShipment(prm)**
**{**
  **return this.http.post(this.url+'LocationApi/SaveShipLocation',prm).toPromise();**

**}**